# How to handle a request in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am a newbie to ColdFusion, I created a `result.cfm` page, now I just want to do some actions in `Application.cfc` when the user calls `/result.cfm`. Something like below:

```html
<cfif 'if the request is for result.cfm'>
<!-- do some action -->
</cfif>
```

Is there any way to handle the request?

Comment: Why do you want to do something in `Application.cfc` for a specific page? Just add that logic to the page itself - `result.cfm`. Here is some documentation on [Request Lifecycle Events](http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/Application_cfc/) in ColdFusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfif REFindNoCase("^/result.cfm", CGI.SCRIPT_NAME)>
  <!--- do some action --->
</cfif>
```

or if you want to match more `pages` and `subfolders` you could do:

```
<cfset patterns = [
    "^/foo/",
    "^/bar/",
    "^/etc/",
    "^/login.cfm",
    "^/baz.cfm"
] />

<cfif REFindNoCase("(" & ArrayToList(patterns, ")|(") & ")", CGI.SCRIPT_NAME)>
    <!--- do some action --->
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 0):

A CFC is what Coldfusion calls a component, but it's essentially an object with methods. When any page on your site is requested coldfusion sends the name of your page to the onRequest method of your Application.cfc. By default that method looks something like this...

```
<cffunction name="OnRequest" access="public" returntype="void" output="true">

    <cfargument name="TargetPage" type="string" required="true" />

    <cfinclude template = "#arguments.targetPage#" />

</cffunction>
```

The TargetPage is the relative path to the page that has been requested.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do do, but you can either just create the page result.cfm and do your coding in there, or if you need to you can intercept the call by creating your own onRequest method and putting it in your application.cfc

```
<cffunction name="OnRequest" access="public" returntype="void" output="true">

    <cfargument name="TargetPage" type="string" required="true" />

    <cfif arguments.targetPage is "requestresult.cfm">
        <!--- Do something else --->
    <cfelse>
        <cfinclude template = "#arguments.targetPage#" />
    </cfif>

</cffunction>
```

Note that onRequest isn't the only method in Application.cfc, so that's worth looking up.
Also note you might want to output arguments.targetPage when you try this to just double check if the slash comes with the request or not (can't remember)